# Show ActionSheet in Popover- what am i doing wrong?

Tags: ios, ipad, actionview, popover

Sams **Teach Yourself iPad Application development in 24 hour's says I can "display an action sheet in a "nonanimated" fashion, filling a full popover view when it first appears...To do this, you need to show the action sheet with the method

> showFromRect:inView:animated

with the "rect" set to the dimensions of the popover, the view set to the popover view controller's view, and "animated" set  to false. The display of the action sheet would need to take place when the popover view is first loaded such as in the viewDidLoad method of the popover view controller.

OK, easy.. here's my code in my popover's viewDidLoad method:

```
- (void)viewDidLoad {

self.contentSizeForViewInPopover=CGSizeMake(400.0,400.0);


    UIActionSheet *actionSheet = [[UIActionSheet alloc] initWithTitle:@"Available Actions" delegate:self cancelButtonTitle:@"Cancel" destructiveButtonTitle:@"Destroy" otherButtonTitles:@"Negotiate", @"Compromise", nil];

    [actionSheet showFromRect:[self.view bounds] inView:self.view  animated:NO];

    [actionSheet release];

    [super viewDidLoad];
}
```

But this fails every time at the `inView:self.view` parameter with the exception:

```
Invalid parameter not satisfying view != nil
```

Any ideas?

Note, if I put this exact same code in an IBAction method and trigger it from a button in the popover, it works without a hitch!

Comment: Try calling `[super viewDidLoad];` before presenting the actionSheet.

Comment: @Pengy +1: Yes, it should be the first call, basically always.

Comment: Are you trying to do this only the first time the view is displayed, or anytime it is displayed?

Comment: Hi - I moved [super viewDidLoad] to the top - no effect.

Comment: The PopOver view is being loaded via a reference in my main view's xib file.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One solution is to call the `UIActionSheet` in `viewWillAppear` or `viewDidAppear`: For example:

```
- (void)viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated {
    [super viewWillAppear:animated];

    [self showActionSheet];
}

- (void)showActionSheet {
    UIActionSheet *actionSheet = [[UIActionSheet alloc] initWithTitle:@"Available Actions" delegate:self cancelButtonTitle:@"Cancel" destructiveButtonTitle:@"Destroy" otherButtonTitles:@"Negotiate", @"Compromise", nil];

    [actionSheet showFromRect:[self.view bounds] inView:self.view  animated:NO];

    [actionSheet release];
}
```

Comment: To test this theory I tried adding a UILabel using [self.view addSubview] and that works fine!

Comment: @PapillonUK: Have you tried calling the actionSheet in `viewWillAppear` instead?

Comment: PengOne - that works! I've never used viewWillAppear before - can you explain why that would work?

Comment: Well, I believe the actionSheet can't be deployed onto a view that isn't currently visible, because the actionSheet needs to block all things behind it. This is a theory. I'll look into it a bit and update my answer.

Comment: OK PengOne - i'll mark that as the answer. Perhaps the Sam's book is incorrect. I also notice that the action sheet still scrolls up in an animated fashion even though I set animated:NO. I think i'm in uncharted territory here - can't seem to find much on this method by Googling either! Thanks for your help!

Comment: @PapillonUK: Books are sometimes fallible. By googling, I found two other posts on other forums with similar issues (never resolved). I think it must be a quirk of UIActionSheet, but I cannot find documentation on it.

Answer (score 0):

`self.view` hasn't been instantiated completely yet when this code is called.

I would suggest, as a hacky alternative, to put in a short (.1 seconds or something) `NSTimer` with your IBAction method as the callback.

Comment: To test this theory I tried adding a UILabel using [self.view addSubview] and that works fine!